# How could I distribute obstacles to my grid without writing them manually?

Tags: python, algorithm, path-finding, a-star

I'm working on A star algorithm and as my code below shown the gird is written manually and I'm thinking to make a grid with 100* 100 size. So, it will be so awful to write them manually. I need to put my starting point at (0,0) location and my goal point at (99,99) location.

I'm trying to make the grid with this line below

```
grid1 = [[0 for i in range(100)]for j in range(100)]
```

But how could I assign obstacles to this grid randomly or not randomly without touching the location of starting point and goal point?

This is below my code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import random

grid = [[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],#0 are free path whereas 1's are obstacles
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]

'''
heuristic = [[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4],
             [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3],
             [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2],
             [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
             [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]]'''

init = [0, 0]
goal = [len(grid)-1, len(grid[0])-1] #all coordinates are given in format [y,x] 
cost = 1

drone_h = 60

#the cost map which pushes the path closer to the goal
heuristic = [[0 for row in range(len(grid[0]))] for col in range(len(grid))]
for i in range(len(grid)):    
    for j in range(len(grid[0])):            
        heuristic[i][j] = abs(i - goal[0]) + abs(j - goal[1])

        #if grid[i][j] == 1:
            #heuristic[i][j] = 99 #added extra penalty in the heuristic map
print(heuristic)
elevation = [[0 for row in range(len(grid[0]))] for col in range(len(grid))]
for i in range(len(grid)):    
    for j in range(len(grid[0])): 
        if grid[i][j] == 1:
            elevation[i][j] = random.randint(1,100)
        else:
            elevation[i][j] = 0



#the actions we can take
delta = [[-1, 0 ], # go up
         [ 0, -1], # go left
         [ 1, 0 ], # go down
         [ 0, 1 ]] # go right


#function to search the path
def search(grid,init,goal,cost,heuristic):

    closed = [[0 for col in range(len(grid[0]))] for row in range(len(grid))]# the referrence grid
    closed[init[0]][init[1]] = 1
    action = [[0 for col in range(len(grid[0]))] for row in range(len(grid))]#the action grid

    x = init[0]
    y = init[1]
    g = 0

    f = g + heuristic[init[0]][init[0]] + elevation[init[0]][init[0]]
    cell = [[f, g, x, y]]

    found = False  # flag that is set when search is complete
    resign = False # flag set if we can't find expand

    while not found and not resign:
        if len(cell) == 0:
            resign = True
            return "FAIL"
        else:
            cell.sort()#to choose the least costliest action so as to move closer to the goal
            cell.reverse()
            next = cell.pop()
            x = next[2]
            y = next[3]
            g = next[1]
            f = next[0]


            if x == goal[0] and y == goal[1]:
                found = True
            else:
                for i in range(len(delta)):#to try out different valid actions
                    x2 = x + delta[i][0]
                    y2 = y + delta[i][1]
                    if x2 >= 0 and x2 < len(grid) and y2 >=0 and y2 < len(grid[0]):
                        if closed[x2][y2] == 0 and grid[x2][y2] == 0 and elevation[x2][y2] < drone_h :
                            g2 = g + cost
                            f2 = g2 + heuristic[x2][y2] + elevation[x2][y2]
                            cell.append([f2, g2, x2, y2])
                            closed[x2][y2] = 1
                            action[x2][y2] = i
    invpath = []
    x = goal[0]
    y = goal[1]
    invpath.append([x, y])#we get the reverse path from here
    while x != init[0] or y != init[1]:
        x2 = x - delta[action[x][y]][0]
        y2 = y - delta[action[x][y]][1]
        x = x2
        y = y2
        invpath.append([x, y])

    path = []
    for i in range(len(invpath)):
        path.append(invpath[len(invpath) - 1 - i])
    print("ACTION MAP")
    for i in range(len(action)):
        print(action[i])

    return path

a = search(grid,init,goal,cost,heuristic)
for i in range(len(a)):
    print(a[i])
```

Comment: What have **you** tried so far? Share your findings/ideas. Where did you get stuck? I would locate the obstacles randomly and than check if they touch the start or end point. If they do, try again.

Comment: just loop through your grid and assign a 1 for certain random number (random.random() >0.7).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could assign the grid randomly and afterwards make sure both starting and end point don't contain obstacles. For neighboring fields you could just do the same as for those two.

```py
import random
grid1 = [[random.randint(0,1) for i in range(100)]for j in range(100)]

# clear starting and end point of potential obstacles
grid1[0][0] = 0
grid1[99][99] = 0
```